# How to sort list of objects

Tags: python

I am learning python, and I do not know what is the best way to sort a list of objects using many attributes. Now I have this

```
class Example:      
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c


List = [Example(3,1,5), Example(2,1,2), Example(2,2,2),  Example(1,4,1),Example(1,4,5), Example(1,4,2)]
```

I do not know how to sort is. Is there any tool in Python to help with this or need to write some custom function?

Comment: You need to specify _how_ you want it sorted. Do you want to sort by `a`, and then by `b`, and then by `c`?

Comment: How do you want the sort to work?  What do you intend the sorted order to be?

Comment: Once you pick the item to sort on (which element in Example, a,b, or c), something like >>> sorted(List, key=lambda element: element[2])   # sort by c

Comment: Checkout the [Sorting How To](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Odd_and_Ends)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by multiple items as follows:

```
List.sort(key=lambda e: [e.a, e.b, e.c])
# or
List.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the easiest way for me now.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) like `__lt__` and `__ne__` in your class in order to be able to sort a list of instances of your class. Rather than implementing all six comparisons, though, we can get away with only implementing two of them (`__eq__` and one of the inequalities) if we decorate with [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

If you want a lexicographic sort, so that you first compare on `a`, and then if tied, compare on `b`, and if still tied, compare on `c`, see below:

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class Example:      
    def __init__(self, a,b,c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and self.c == other.c:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.a < other.a:
            return True
        elif self.a == other.a and self.b < other.b:
            return True
        elif self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b and self.c < other.c:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __repr__(self): # included for readability in an interactive session
        return 'Example({}, {}, {})'.format(self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

Now, we can do the following:

```
>>> lst = [Example(3,1,5), Example(2,1,2), Example(2,2,2),  Example(1,4,1),Example(1,4,5), Example(1,4,2)]
>>> lst
[Example(3, 1, 5), Example(2, 1, 2), Example(2, 2, 2), Example(1, 4, 1), Example(1, 4, 5), Example(1, 4, 2)]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst
[Example(1, 4, 1), Example(1, 4, 2), Example(1, 4, 5), Example(2, 1, 2), Example(2, 2, 2), Example(3, 1, 5)]
```

Comment: Or we can simply do: `lst.sort(key=operator.attrgetter('a', 'b', 'c'))`

Comment: Even if you were going this route, I think it's simpler to implement a key function of some kind which returns the tuple `(a,b,c)`.  Then `__eq__` is simply `return self.key() == other.key()` and `__lt__` is simply `return self.key() < other.key()`.

Comment: @200OK Yup, that certainly is a clean way to do the sort if OP just wants a lexicographic sort. I figured it would be good to put an example with comparison methods out here in case OP wants something more general.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on what you are planning on sorting by. However, whatever that may be you are probably looking for a lambda function. Say you wanted to sort by the self.a attribute you would write your sort as such

```
#[Example(3, 1, 5), Example(2, 1, 2), Example(2, 2, 2), Example(1, 4, 1), Example(1, 4, 5), Example(1, 4, 2)]

List.sort(key=lambda x: x.a, reverse=False)

#[Example(1, 4, 1), Example(1, 4, 2), Example(1, 4, 5), Example(2, 1, 2), Example(2, 2, 2), Example(3, 1, 5)]
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be, as @senshin already explained, to make the object ordered. That works if `Example` is ordered inherently and that ordering can be also used e.g. to compare standalone objects. However, if your sorting order may vary, then `sorted` or `list.sort` with `key` argument is what you need, and [`operator` module functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Operator_Module_Functions) can make it more elegant:

```
from operator import attrgetter
sorted(alist, key=attrgetter('a'))      # sort just by a
sorted(alist, key=attrgetter('c', 'b')) # sort by c then by b
```